# Can I view a file that is in a shared Windows directory from a Linux system without mounting the directory?

Tags: linux, windows, share

I have a shared Windows directory that can be accessed via `\\SERVERNAME\Path\To\File\`, and I can easily read files from this directory on Windows systems, but I'm not sure how to access these files from a Linux system. I've seen numerous ways where people mount the share on the Linux system; but I don't want to mount it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `smbclient` command line utility will allow you to browse and work with remote Windows shares.

The simplest usage would be:

```
smbclient //fileserver/fileshare
```

See the man page for more options such as specifying the server IP address if NetBIOS resolution fails, operations you can use to browse or get files, etc.